# Uniformity assumption on piecewise uniformly continuous function

Tags: real-analysis

I am interested in a function $f$ which is piecewise uniformly continuous i.e. there exists a (possibly infinite) sequence  of open intervals $\{(t_i,t_{i+1})\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ such that for each $\epsilon>0$   $\exists \:\delta_i(\epsilon)>0$ with $|f(\bar{t}_2)-f(\bar{t}_1)|\leq \epsilon$ for all $|\bar{t}_2-\bar{t}_1|\leq \delta_i(\epsilon)$ and $\bar{t}_1,\bar{t}_2\in(t_i,t_{i+1})$, $\forall i=1,2,\ldots$.

I want to further impose a uniformity assumption on the above property, i.e. assume that we can find a function $\delta(\epsilon)>0$  such that for each $\epsilon>0$    we have $|f(\bar{t}_2)-f(\bar{t}_1)| \leq\epsilon$ for all $|\bar{t}_2-\bar{t}_1|\leq \delta(\epsilon)$ and $\bar{t}_1,\bar{t}_2\in(t_i,t_{i+1})$,  $\forall i=1,2,\ldots$.

Is there a name for this property? And if not how would you suggest to call it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably a good name is

> *uniformly piecewise continuous*

since typically "uniformly something" means that the whole something holds in a single uniform way.

Then you can say u.p.c. implies p.u.c., because "$\exists \delta\forall i$" implies "$\forall i\exists\delta$".

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the function is not even continuous at the times $t_i$. The second property holds only for $\bar{t}_1,\bar{t}_{2}$ in the specific interval $(t_i,t_{i+1})$   but with uniform $\delta$.

Comment: Based on your reasoning I think that the term "uniformly piecewise uniformly continuous"  should be more proper but it sounds horrible!

Comment: On a second thought I think you are correct in the sense that a continuous function in a bounded interval is always uniformly continuous and therefore the second "uniformity" is redundant.